# Jqtree calling data from server without url

Tags: jqtree

I am starting with jqtree and I need to load data from server, without url (I have seen examples of loading ajax data from url, and it's not what I need) and I haven't found anything about that anywhere. Does someone know how can I set a jqtree treeview calling the data from the server? Also, how should I return the json node list?

Answer (score 1):

A server request needs a URL. That's how HTTP works.

An alternative you can try is to put the data directly into the page which initializes the jqtree. The data attribute can directly be given a JS object.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, but first I must convert the data to JSON in .NET and then throw it to jquery to catch it. Now my question is: how can I call an ajax function from jqtree and get a JSON list to set the treeview?

Comment: So you're generating the HTML page which will contain the jqtree in .NET? Then surely you can use some .NET library to generate a JSON string, and embed that into your generated page.

Comment: Here's the code I got from right here, stackoverflow, to format the string into the JSON data jqtree expects.